# How to prepend user input data to a filename uploaded through Sprout Forms

Tags: craft3, plugin-sproutforms, files

I have a contact form where users have to fill in a name field and upload a file.  I want to add the name the user filled in to the beginning of the filename, eg: firstname-lastname_filename.pdf.  I am using Sprout Forms for Craft 3, both the most up to date versions.

Is this something I can do with original Sprout Forms functionality, or will I have to write a custom module or plugin to inject this code?  Essentially, what I understand is I will have to find the code in Sprout Forms where the file is uploaded, and inject the code to add the special user submitted name data.

Answer (score 2):

[Sprout forms has hooks](https://sprout.barrelstrengthdesign.com/docs/forms/events-and-hooks.html#events) you can latch on to in your own custom module/plugin, so when a form is saved you can grab the asset and re-name at that point.